# PHP does not work over ssl connections

Tags: php, apache, ssl, mod-ssl

I just got my ssl certificate to work for the first time.
For some reason when I connect to my website using https my browser tries to download the php file.

I have the following line in my httpd.conf. Isn't this the line which makes sure php files are run using php?

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

What else do I need to change so that I can get the php files to work over the https connection.

Thanks!

UPDATE:

httpd.conf:

`Removed...`

Comment: where is that AddType is it nested anywhere? What does the mod_ssl config look like inside there too?

Comment: "AddType application/x-httpd-php .php" is located both in httpd.conf and in ssl.conf. 

What exactly would you like to learn about the mod_ssl config?

Comment: post your httpd.conf in its entirety for a faster solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was somehow with Plesk. This dedicated server came with plesk pre-installed. I never used it so far but it turns out it was overriding my ssl.conf somehow.

So the solution was creating my domain under plesk. Moving all files to the new directory created by plesk. Embedding my ssl certificate to plesk and associating the certificate with the domain.

Now it is working like a charm. I cannot say I'm happy that I have to start learning Plesk but at least it is working.